# Custom Control Dependency Property collection, counts nested control items

Tags: wpf

I have created two custom controls. 1. A LeafControl 2- LeafItemControl. 
In LeafControl, i created a Dependency Property of type "List" as "Items".

- Also in LeafItemControl i exposed one more dependency property call "ItemDetails" of type ContentControl.

  ```
  <!---Base Custom Control "LeafControl"-->
  ```

  ```
       <uc:LeafControlItem.ItemDetails> <!--"ItemDetails" is a Dependency Property of type "LeafControl" in "LeafControlItem" custom control -->
          <uc:LeafControl> <!--Nested Control of same type ???-->
          <uc:LeafControl.Items>
           <uc:LeafControlItem Level="Some Type">
              <uc:LeafControlItem.ItemContent>
                  <GroupBox BorderThickness="0">
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBox Text="Property"></TextBox>
                      </StackPanel>
                  </GroupBox>
              </uc:LeafControlItem.ItemContent> 

              </uc:LeafControlItem>
              <uc:LeafControlItem Level="Variable">
                <uc:LeafControlItem.ItemContent>
                                      <GroupBox BorderThickness="0">
                                          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                              <TextBox Text="Ellipse2.Top"></TextBox>
                                          </StackPanel>
                                      </GroupBox>
                                  </uc:LeafControlItem.ItemContent>
                              </uc:LeafControlItem>
                          </uc:LeafControl.Items>
                      </uc:LeafControl>  
                  </uc:LeafControlItem.ItemDetails>
              </uc:LeafControlItem>
  ```

When i try to access the "Items" in the base custom control. all the child custom controls are getting added why ?  What should i do so that each custom control objects (base and child) have there individual "Items".

I have used Dependency Property in Base Custom Control like this :

```
 #region LeafControlItemCollection 

        public List<LeafControlItem> Items
        {
            get { return (List<LeafControlItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(
              "Items", typeof(List<LeafControlItem>), typeof(LeafControl),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<LeafControlItem>(), null, null)
            ); 
#endregion
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Comment: Hi Thanks ! that worked. Also i found another approach. Exposing "Items" Dependency Property data type as "ItemsControl". And in xaml i can add Items to it like anyother  itemscontrol. It also works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is in the declaration of dependency property identifier i.e. `ItemsProperty`. You have provided a `default value as new List<LeafControlItem>()`. By doing this you have created a `singleton instance for your list` under the wraps.

Read it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx#initializing), it describes exactly the same problem which you are encountering with default initialization of list DP. Quote from that link -

> If your property is a reference type, the default value specified in
>   dependency property metadata is not a default value per instance;
>   instead it is a default value that applies to all instances of the
>   type. Therefore you must be careful to not use the singular static
>   collection defined by the collection property metadata as the working
>   default value for newly created instances of your type. Instead, you
>   must make sure that you deliberately set the collection value to a
>   unique (instance) collection as part of your class constructor logic.
>   Otherwise you will have created an unintentional singleton class.

Specifing default value as `new List<LeafControlItem>()`, make all the instances of `LeafControl` to share the same instance of list. So, any addition and deletion of object in that list will be reflected across all the instances of LeafControl. So, actually you have created singleton list here for all instances of LeafControl.

First of all you should avoid specifying new List in default value -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(
              "Items", typeof(List<LeafControlItem>), typeof(LeafControl));
```

And second, you should initialise it to new list by setting it in a constructor of your ListControl class so that every instance has its own share of list -

```
public LeafControl()
{
   SetValue(ItemsPropertyKey, new List<LeafControlItem>()); 
}
```